# Merge HEAD to master

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have problems with merging HEAD to master, when executing git merge master - I get "already updated"
Help please, thanks

```
* 0b3b69b - (35 минут назад) chart on exchange page - Little Whale (HEAD)
* 8f52f4b - (6 часов назад) exchange modul works correctly - Little Whale
* a6c836e - (2 дня назад) commit for checkout on other commit - Little Whale (master)
* 9e59520 - (2 дня назад) pie chart renders correctly - Little Whale
* f57ace2 - (2 дня назад) input group in portfolio page are fixed and works correctly - Little Whale
* 3a45fc1 - (3 дня назад) exchange block implemented - Little Whale
* 75f7ca9 - (4 дня назад) portfolio was done - Little Whale
* 5ea03ec - (5 дней назад) currency block and pie chart implemented - Little Whale
* 8913e2c - (5 дней назад) Initialize project using Create React App - Little Whale
```

Comment: Use `--graph` on the log command.... plus we don't get to see where master is. If master is a direct ancestor of HEAD, merge won't work.... if what you want is to have master move to HEAD is, you might move it with `git branch -f master` (that is, if masyer is a direct ancestor of HEAD).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on [eftshift0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2437508/eftshift0)'s comment, the full command to use would be:

```
git log --decorate --online --graph --all --branches
```

You would then be able to see where HEAD is positioned, relative to `master`.

As [LeGEC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86072/legec) comments, a more focused command would be:

```
git log --decorate --online --graph HEAD master
```

Comment: For this question's sake : perhaps drop the `--all`, and end the command with `git log ... HEAD master`

Comment: @LeGEC Good point, I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: after re-reading the OP's question : it *does* look like the output of `git log --oneline --graph`, doesn't it ?

Comment: @LeGEC Sure, but I always prefer to add at least `--decorate`, in order to see the HEAD and branch names.

Answer (score 0):

From the output of your log command : it looks that your current `master` branch (commit `a6c836e`) is indeed already part of `HEAD`'s history -- `HEAD` (commit `0b3b69b`) is two commits *ahead* of `master`. So there is nothing more to merge from `master` into your current commit.

If your intention is to have `master` move forward to `0b3b69b`, you should merge the other way around :

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only 0b3b69b
```

---

In your situation, the `--ff-only` is not necessary (you already know it will be a fast forward merge) ;
in a more general usage : in situations where you want to avoid to create a useless merge commit if you can, this option makes sure that it won't happen without you realizing it.